# Store a database name in variable & then using it dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table in my Database  Which have name of all the Database of my Server

Table Look like

```
   create   Table  #db_name_list(Did INT IDENTITY(1,1), DNAME NVARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO #db_name_list
    SELECT 'db_One ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'db_Two' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'db_Three' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'db_four' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'db_five'

select * from #db_name_list
```

I have so many SP in my Database..Which uses multiple table and Join Them..

At Present I am using the SQL code like

```
Select Column from db_One..Table1
Left outer join db_two..Table2
on ....some Condition ....
```

REQUIREMENT
But I do not want to HARDCODE the DATABASE Name ..

I want store DataBase name in Variable and use that .
Reason :: I want to restore same Database with Different name and want to Run those SP..At Present we Cant Do ,Because I have used db_One..Table1
or db_two..Table2

I want some thing like ...

/*SAMPLE SP*/

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(500)
  set @dbname=(  SELECT DNAME FROM #db_name_list WHERE Did=1)
 set @dbname2=(  SELECT DNAME FROM #db_name_list WHERE Did=2)
  PRINT @DBNAME
  SELECT * FROM   @dbname..table1 
  /* or */
  SELECT * FROM   @dbname2.dbo.table1

END
```

i.e using Variable Instead of Database name ..
But it thow error

> "Incorrect syntax near '.'."

P.S This was posted by some else on msdn but the answer there was not clear & I had the same kind of doubt. So please help

Comment: Is this the page where the question was asked previously? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f52d3506-8d89-461e-97ac-f77972239aed/sqlreplace-database-name-with-variable?forum=sqlintegrationservices  The answer there is pretty simple, you need to create a variable called @SQL, pass your query an DB name variable into the string and execute that as shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable like this in a *static* sql query. You have to use the variable in *dynamic* sql instead, in order to build the query you want to execute, like:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @dbname + '.dbo.mytable'

EXEC(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of options for you depending on your circumstances.

**1. Simple - Generalise your procedures**

Simply take out the database references in your stored procedure, as there is no need to have an explicit reference to the database if it is running against the database it is stored in. Your select queries will look like:

```
SELECT * from schema.table WHERE x = y
```

Rather than

```
SELECT * from database.schema.table WHERE x = y
```

Then just create the stored procedure in the new database and away you go. Simply connect to the new database and run the SP. This method would also allow you to promote the procedure to being a system stored procedure, which would mean they were automatically available in every database without having to run `CREATE` beforehand. For more details, see [this article](http://sqlrus.com/2011/10/add-a-procedure-to-master-database-yes-please/).

**2. Moderate - Dynamic SQL**

Change your stored procedure to take a database name as a parameter, such as this example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example (@DatabaseName VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM ['+@DatabaseName+'].schema.table WHERE x = y'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```